# check if the string contains alphabets in php

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, preg-match

How to check if the string has alphabets in PHP

The [ctype_alpha](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) and  [ctype_digit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) doesn't help in it. is their any method?

Comment: Can you post the failure test case of `ctype_alpha` ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran it only checks for alphabets.. if it finds alhanumeric it returns false

Comment: `ctype_alpha` Returns `TRUE` if **every character** in text is a letter from the current locale, `FALSE` otherwise. Does your string contain all letters?

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` alpha, `/^[0-9]+$/` num, `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` alpha-num.

Comment: @user1765876, Well.. what do you expect from it ? If you are looking for alphanumeric then you should go for `ctype_alnum`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I was looking for the function that searches IF the string has alphabets if any then return true, 1234e, on this string _alpha returns false..

Comment: Or, `/^\pL+$/` Uni alpha, `/^\pN+$/` Uni num, `/^[\pL\pN]+$/` Uni alpha-num

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use `preg_match` for this.

```
if(preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $string)){
    print "it has alphabet!";
}
```

If you want to check for all the characters to be alphabet, then use anchor around the regex. For example `^[a-z]+$`.

Answer (score 8):

Posted as requested

`/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` alpha, `/^[0-9]+$/` num, `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` alpha-num

or

`/^\pL+$/u` Uni alpha, `/^\pN+$/u` Uni num, `/^[\pL\pN]+$/u` Uni alpha-num